# Get multipe response using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, xampp

Is it possible to get multiple responses using AJAX and PHP?

The event triggered by a select box and when it changes value (`onchange`) it calls the JavaScript function and get `xmlhttp.responseText`.

But on `responseText` we can only change one value/innerHtml based on id.
I want to change 2 or more HTML using AJAX. Is it possible?

Here is my AJAX function:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtStockQTY"+baris).value = "Validating..";
    }
    else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtStockQTY"+baris).value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxGetStock.php?id="+id, true);
xmlhttp.send();`
```

And `ajaxGetStock` follows:

```
$idbarang = $_GET['id'];
include "../connect.php";

$resultSetStockType = mysql_query("SELECT STOCK_QTY,STOCK_QTYUNIT,STOCK_SIZE,STOCK_SIZE2 FROM TSTOCK WHERE STOCK_ID = $idbarang",$con);

if($resultSetStockType and mysql_num_rows($resultSetStockType) > 0) {
    while($rowSetStockType = mysql_fetch_array($resultSetStockType)) {
        echo $rowSetStockType['STOCK_QTY']." ".$rowSetStockType['STOCK_QTYUNIT'];
    }
}
else {
    echo "--- stok tidak ditemukan ---";
}
```

I want to get several return values from my AJAX and assign it to several inputs of type text.

Comment: DON'T USE `mysql_*` METHODS AS THEY ARE DEPRECATED AND HAVE BEEN REMOVED AS OF PHP 7.

Comment: I advice you to use formated texts like "JSON" : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: thanks for the comment, guys. Perharps I'm gonna try mysqli_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return JSON like this in php:

```
return json_encode([
    'firstValue ' => 'my first value',
    'secondValue' => 'my second value'
]);
```

Then in JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("txtStockQTY"+baris).value = data.firstValue;
```

Note: I hate jQuery except for one thing: ajax calls. I advise you to use it in order to avoid all these lines of code that makes the code hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing the results straight from the database, you need to store them in an array and echo the JSON encoded array.

```
$array = array();
while($rowSetStockType = mysql_fetch_array($resultSetStockType)){
  $tempval =  $rowSetStockType['STOCK_QTY']." ".$rowSetStockType['STOCK_QTYUNIT'];

  $array.push($tempval);
}

//When its done processing all the returned values, echo json_encoded array.

echo json_encode($array);
```

you will then have access to the array from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem, i'll try to explain some of them.

**Return HTML elements**

Return HTML code with inputs from your AJAX code and add them to a div with the use of `innerHTML` instead of `.value` like you are doing now.

**Return JSON**

Return the code as a JSON object with `json_encode` and use JavaScript JSON functions to populate your inputs. Alan Tan already provided you with an example while I'm typing this.